# Entity Framework SQLMigration Error for "update-database": Command "update" is not valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to EF and MVC3.  I'm running through the following MVC3 SQL Migration tutorial (link below) and when I run the following command from a cmd window with VS2010 I get the following error:

> update-database

Command "update" is not valid

What am I missing here?  Thx!

Tutorial Link:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute it from `package manager console` not from the command prompt.In VS 2010 go to

> View -> Other Windows -> package manager console

and try executing the command.

And also you need to use correct version of entity framework (Entity Framework 4.1 - Update 1). Try installing this http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26825